# Method not working in my tic tac toe game

Tags: c#, winforms

If I pass this code then it works.

```
if (textBox1.Text == "1:1" && xOneOne == false && oOneOne == false)
{
    oOneOne = true;
    xOneOne = false;
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Lauks ir aiznjemts xDDDD");
}
```

But I wanted to create Method so i don't need to copy this same code over and over again. The method isn't working. I guess it doesn't refresh the picturebox because I don't get the image.

My method:

```
private void Aplis(TextBox textBox, string koordinatas, bool xVertiba, bool oVertiba, PictureBox PictureBox)
{
    if (textBox.Text == koordinatas && xVertiba == false && oVertiba == false)
    {
        oVertiba = true;
        xVertiba = false;
        PictureBox.Refresh();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Lauks ir aiznjemts xDDDD");
    }
}
```

And I try to call it out like this instead of my first code:

```
Aplis(textBox1, "1:1", xOneOne, oOneOne, pictureBox1);
```

Comment: Do not name objects the same as their types. Maybe PictureBox got a static method Refresh which is being called instead of the one You want?(it doesn't but this could be an issue)

Comment: `xOneOne == false && oOneOne == false` _*eye twitches*_

Answer (score 7):

You are setting two booleans inside your method:

```
oVertiba = true;
xVertiba = false;
```

These don't set the actual values passed in, just the value inside the method. You can pass them in as `ref`, which will give you the ability to alter them:

```
private void Aplis( TextBox textBox
                  , string koordinatas
                  , ref bool xVertiba
                  , ref bool oVertiba
                  , PictureBox PictureBox
                  )
{ }
```

Note you have to use the `ref` keyword too when passing the values in.

Also, `xVertiba == false` can be simplified as `!xVertiba`, `xVertiba == true` just as `xVertiba`.